# How to repair backpack inside surface?

Tags: backpacks, repairs

I have a backpack that is about fifteen years old. The interior surface becomes a little sticky from the deterioration of the coating or material. How to repair this?

Comment: This Q will also have useful advice in the answers: https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/8922/cleaning-the-plastic-residue-of-the-inside-of-my-old-backpack?rq=1